# Get user friends using a web app with Facebook Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have done a lot of research regarding this issue and I cannot find a way to retrieve all the friends of a user that are using a web app.

I don't believe that it cannot be do it with the Graph Facebook Api.

Having a "user_token" I can retrieve a list of all the friends with `https://graph.facebook.com/me/` but still I am cannot find the way to do it just with the friends using an app.

I have tried something like `https://graph.facebook.com/{ID_APP}/friends` but it is not working at all.

I really appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you authenticate the friends that are using your app. You need to ask for a certain permission (check the documentation) in order to view the friendlist. When the users of your app granted your app access to read your friends, you should be able to successfully call https://graph.facebook.com/{USER_ID}/friends. Dont forget to supply the granted access token of the user who uses your app!

Comment: The thing is that I already tried the "https://graph.facebook.com/{USER_ID}/friends" statement and it gives me all the friend user and not only the one that are using the app.

I believe my access_token is right but if you tell me that this is the way maybe I have something wrong with the token.

Thanks!

Comment: Also I am trying with the Facebook debugger selecting my app on right corner and writing in the input: 'http://graph.facebook.com{MYUSER_ID}/friends' and it gives to me all my friends.
And the token Facebook is giving to me for testing should be the one for the app I just selected.

Comment: You have to supply the access token of the authenticated user, not the access token of your application. When a user grants your application access to his friend list, you get an access token. You have to use that access token to get HIS friends. There is not 1 access token, every user has its own access token when it grants your app permission to view his friend list. Make sure you supply the correct access token and not the same (your app access token) over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

To get a users friends list (assuming they are connected to your app):

`FB.api('/me/friends?fields=installed,id,name', function (response { window.console.log(response); });`